# kendo observable set object in array

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a kendo observable with datasource thats an array

```
var vm = kendo.observable({
dataSource:[ { name: "Jane Doe" }, { name: "John Doe" }]
});
```

I bind it to a list view

```
<div data-role="listView" id ="listView" data-bind="source:dataSource" data-template="template"></div>

  <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
  <div>#:name#</div>
  </script>
<script>
kendo.bind($('#listView'),vm);
```

Is it possible to change the name of the first object in the array without setting the whole array?

I'm trying  `vm.get('dataSource')[0].set('name','lun');` but its not working

Here is a link of the problem http://dojo.telerik.com/OrAjE/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the `<div>` element that displays the `name` property with a MVVM text binding. The #:{field}# syntax provides one-way binding.

This is how the template should look like:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
  <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
</script>
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/OrAjE/5